# Can I simplify this code with an HTML Helper?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following code on my web pages:

```
<div class="rep_tb0" id="Activity" style="display:none;">
    <div class="rep_tr0">
        <div class="rep_td0" id="ActivityLog">Activity Log<br /><br /></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It's repeated for many pages and I would like to just code it once in one place. Can anyone tell me what are my options for doing this. Can I code an HTML Helper or is there a better / another way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, build an HTML helper by creating an extension method.  It's a lot easier than you think.

Check out this article:
http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2011/03/23/comparing-mvc-3-helpers-using-extension-methods-and-declarative-razor-helper.aspx

Or this article:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to use a partial in this case. Just create a .cshtml file and put that code in. Then call

```
@Html.Partial("PartialName");
```